# Keep on getting error on website using AnchorCMS

Tags: php, web, content-management-system, blogs

I’m attempting to use AnchorCMS. I keep on getting this message at the bottom of my page.

```
    Uncaught Exception
    Undefined offset: 6
    Origin
    on line 90
    Trace
    #0 [internal function]: System\Error::shutdown()
    #1 {main}
```

I’ve already tried deleting and reloading all files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also have the same problem as you. I tried to edit in `Anchor/config/error.php` `report => true` to `report => false`, but I’ve got a server error. Then I deleted the value (`true` or `false`), left it blank, and it succeed.

Comment: So get rid of the `true` and `false` and keep it as `'report' => ,` ?