# Have an error on every page using AnchorCMS

Tags: php, anchor-cms

I am using AnchorCMS and I am getting the same message on every page:

```
Uncaught Exception
Undefined offset: 6
Origin
on line 90
Trace
#0 [internal function]: System\Error::shutdown()
#1 {main}
```

I have already seen [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19943071/keep-on-getting-error-on-website-using-anchorcms) but it does not fix the problem in a "clean" way (it's just a workaround I think).